# Is there a javascript implementation for R's qnorm function?

Tags: javascript, statistics

I am trying to get z-score (or simply score) in a normal distribution just like the R `qnorm` function does, but with javascript.

In R it is like this:

```
> qnorm(0.90, mean = 1500, sd = 300)
[1] 1884.465
```

Is there such a (hopefully light) implementation for javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Did you](https://rangevoting.org/Qnorm.html) [google enough?](https://gist.github.com/dtuite/7184780)

```js
var qnorm = function(p) {

  p = parseFloat(p);
  var split = 0.42;

  var a0 = 2.50662823884;
  var a1 = -18.61500062529;
  var a2 = 41.39119773534;
  var a3 = -25.44106049637;
  var b1 = -8.47351093090;
  var b2 = 23.08336743743;
  var b3 = -21.06224101826;
  var b4 = 3.13082909833;
  var c0 = -2.78718931138;
  var c1 = -2.29796479134;
  var c2 = 4.85014127135;
  var c3 = 2.32121276858;
  var d1 = 3.54388924762;
  var d2 = 1.63706781897;

  var q = p - 0.5;

  var r, ppnd;

  if (Math.abs(q) <= split) {
    r = q * q;
    ppnd = q * (((a3 * r + a2) * r + a1) * r + a0) / ((((b4 * r + b3) * r + b2) * r + b1) * r + 1);
  } else {
    r = p;
    if (q > 0) r = 1 - p;
    if (r > 0) {
      r = Math.sqrt(-Math.log(r));
      ppnd = (((c3 * r + c2) * r + c1) * r + c0) / ((d2 * r + d1) * r + 1);
      if (q < 0) ppnd = -ppnd;
    } else {
      ppnd = 0;
    }
  }

  return ppnd;
}

console.log(qnorm(.432423));
```

Comment: Yes, I also saw exact same repo. Even though it fully answers the question, it is not the exact form of R's qnorm. Additionally I was expecting a more comprehensive - but still light - library. Anyhow, thanks a lot for the answer. I'll throw the remaining math to get the score from z-score.

Comment: I would like to extend it by my math ends in standard deviation :(